# How to make mvc action fire off jquery ajax converter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller, converters

How do I make a mvc controller action hit an ajax converter. Can I modify the response to fire off this

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    converters: {
        "mytype1 mytype2": function (result) {
            //do stuff
            return newresult;
        }
    }
});
```

I have tried changing the content-type and content-encoding of the JsonResult like this:

```
result.ContentType = "mytype1";
..
response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "mytype1");
```

But to no awail..

Edit:

What I really want is to change the return type of my mvc action and add an ajax converter ("mytype1 json") and still have all the existing $.ajax-calls that expect json to work

Comment: what are you returning from the server xml? json?

Comment: So far I've have only tried JsonResult..

Answer (score 0):

i'll assume you are returning the `json` from the server, you can extract the json in the converter and return your own type

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    converters: {
        "json mytype2": function (result) {
            //do stuff            
            return newresult;
        }
    }
});
```

then you can make the normal ajax call

```
$.ajax({
 url:'',
 type:'',
 dataType:'json mytype2',
 success:function(data){
  // data will be newresult
 }
});
```

you dont have to call the converter explicitly from the server side

Comment: Yes. I had noticed that. I was hoping to explicitly call the converter. I will edit my question to reflect what I really want.